# Cognitive Services Topic Detection API not returning any results

Tags: c#, swagger

I can't seem to get any results back from the Cognitive Services Text Analytics API for Topic Detection. I downloaded the "API definition" and generated the REST API Client into a C# project using the Swagger metadata file that I downloaded.

I'm running a test that included 2000+ small sentences that include common phrases so the detection should work. The code is constructed as follows:

1. I created an `TopicDetectionInputV2` object to which I added the 2000+ `InputV2` documents.  Tried with and without the `StopWords` and `TopicsToExclude`.
2. I created an `AzureMachineLearningTextAnalytics` object that I call the `DetectTopics(key, null, null, null, TopicDetectionInputV2)`.  Tried both min/max documents per word set.

I always receive a null response from the API call.

When I debug into the generated REST API call and inspect the `httpResponse`, it always returns a `Status Code: 202` and `ReasonPhrase: 'Accepted'`, however the response body is empty.

Has anyone been able to get actual results from the DetectTopics API? Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this API, but according to the documentation this is the expected behavior.

[DetectTopics API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3ca) will either return a 202  (processing) or 400 (error).

Once the request has successfully been submitted, which is appears that it has, you should get the result using the [OperationStatus API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c8).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that in the API call, I assumed the synchronous call would do all that for me, however inspecting the generated method it doesn't.