# Cognitive Services Operation Status API not returning any results

Tags: c#, swagger

As per this link, [Cognitive Services Topic Detection API not returning any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468148/cognitive-services-topic-detection-api-not-returning-any-results/41508967#41508967])!

I have tried calling the OperationStatus API after the request from DetectTopics API has successfully been submitted. I created an `AzureMachineLearningTextAnalytics` object that I call the *OperationStatus (OperationId , Key).*

The response that I got back was : *Status : RanToCompletion*.

The result is however coming as null and the error message that I got when I debug into the generated REST API call was

> "Internal error while executing BES operation".*

Has anyone been able to get results from the OperationStatus API? Can anyone please provide any suggestions regarding this issue ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please see the link for additional details.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468148/cognitive-services-topic-detection-api-not-returning-any-results/41508967#41508967

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Azure Cognative Services Text Analytics REST APIS with the generated Swagger definitions, use the WithOperationalResponseAsync method to get the operational response related to the request.  From that you can query the status of the original request.  A simplified C# example is as follows:

```
    AzureMachineLearningTextAnalytics textAnalyzer = new AzureMachineLearningTextAnalytics();
var topicResult = textAnalyzer.DetectTopicsWithOperationResponseAsync(textAnalyticsAccountKey, null, null, null, topicDetection);
string operationId = topicResult.Result.Response.Headers.Location.Segments[topicResult.Result.Response.Headers.Location.Segments.Length - 1];
var status = textAnalyzer.OperationStatus(operationId, textAnalyticsAccountKey);

while ((((MySample.TextAnalytics.Models.OperationResult)status).Status == "NotStarted") ||
       (((MySample.TextAnalytics.Models.OperationResult)status).Status == "Running"))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
    status = textAnalyzer.OperationStatus(operationId, textAnalyticsAccountKey);
}

if (((Terawe.Retail.TextAnalytics.Models.OperationResult)status).Status == "Failed")
{
    // Log an error to the console
    Console.WriteLine($"Topic detection failed with status: {((MySample.TextAnalytics.Models.OperationResult)status).Message}");
}
else
{
    // Process the phrases
}
```